# Чем воспользоваться при создании приложения для Android?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Ситуация: обучаюсь на первом курсе магистратуры в электротехническом. Начрук на магистерскую (до нее есть времени где-то 1.5 года) дал задание написать программу на андрюшу, которая по wifi принимала бы сигнал (условно с датчика ЭКГ) и производила бы его обработку с показом результата. С программированием дроида я раньше не сталкивался, поэтому полез искать инструменты выполнения. И тут полезли непонятки, какой из них выбрать. С одной стороны люди пишут про возможность использовать phonegap, а я хорошо знаю html/css и имею представление о js. Но с другой стороны пишется, что при этом возможности будут существенно ограничены. Вот и возник вопрос, хватит ли этих возможностей, чтобы реализовать ТЗ ?

Или лучше сразу взяться за изучение java (а если не java, то что еще можно?)? 
Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Java и C++, с wifi что-то другое врядли будет работать.

Comment: Проще сделать так чтобы сигнал с датчика передавался на удаленный http сервер, обрабатывался там, а само приложение было бы просто интерфейсной оберткой для связи с сервером. Java + Eclipse + Android SDK должно хватить для этого вполне. Сервер можно программировать на чем угодно.

Comment: Молодец начрук: задание как бы плевое, но чтобы ее сделать надо пахать как вол с полгода. Не все еще в нашей системе образования потрачено.

Comment: вы сначала определитесь с вай-фай: кто точкой доступа будет?.. если ваш датчик-клиент умеет цепляться за готовую чью-то вайфай, а программа должна также цепляться к уже готовой вай-фай сетке и искать нужного клиента,- то это одно фонгап может справиться, но если сама программа для андроида должна стать ТД и ловить все рядом стоящие ви-фи клиенты, опознавать их и фильтровать нужный -- то это совсем другое, ту точно джава нужна.

Comment: Скорее этот вариант: "сама программа для андроида должна стать ТД и ловить все рядом стоящие ви-фи клиенты...". Благодарю за ответы. И, дабы не гневить Оккама, еще один вопросик тут: что посоветуете для изучения джавы -  Эккеля или Хорстмана?

Comment: Если ограничиться только этими двумя вариантами, то Хорстманн будет нужнее в Вашем случае. По факту, Вам для старта в Android нужен Java Core, не более. Хорошие курсы есть от Головача на YouTube, Вам этого будет вполне достаточно. А потом погружайтесь в Android SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Беритесь сразу за изучение Java. PhoneGap это слишком хитрая поделушка сделанная поверх `WebView` у нее довольно ограниченная функциональность заточенная прежде всего для создания красявого юзер интерфейса. Серьезную бизнес-логику она не потянет - маловато инструментов. Все равно придется писать логику под Java.

Comment: @Barmaley, при всем уважении - вы слишком категоричны

Answer (score 1):

Java(JDK) + Eclipse IDE(Classic, Java IDE) + Android SDK + плагин разработки под дроид от Google для Eclipse + реальный девайс = ваше счастье на 99.99999999%

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую IntelliJ Idea 
мне после всех Java IDE она больше всех понравилась

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то будет писать подобное, в [этом репозитории](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent) можно найти веб-компонент, предоставляющий очень удобный коллбек для отображения удара сердца.

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<ecg-line></ecg-line>';
ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
```

Для быстрой разработки ui для веб, который потом сам по себе не перестанет собираться из-за прекращения поддержки npm пакетов, можно использовать [этот](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/material-ui-umd/blob/master/packages/form-generator-app/STUDENTS.md) инструмент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]